# Android make a runnable run only once

Tags: android, runnable

Hi i have an animation that i'm wanting to delay the start of with a runnable however its cause the animation to loop which i don't need i just want it to delay and then run once does anyone know how?

heres my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_initialsetup);
        handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                animations();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
    }


    public void animations(){
        image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.su_shirts);
        AnimationMovepos = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shirt_anim);   
        image.startAnimation(AnimationMovepos); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is looping because inside the runnable you are posting it again to the handler with this call:

```
handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
```

remove that and it won't loop

Comment: thank you this was correct i can't accept for 10 minutes but will do when i can

Comment: he is too close to a black hole.

Comment: Almost 2017 and 10 mins still running.

Comment: Its 2018 and 10 minutes still running :p

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);` in your `run()` method.